# Escape Characters in d3.js ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I need to display micromoles per liter (µmol/L) in my chart's tickFormat, but when I pass in "&#181;mol/L", it shows the characters "&#181;" instead of the symbol for mu.  How do I get it to render the symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, you shouldn't use an HTML entity. Once you're dealing with an SVG , use this:

```
\u00B5
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 500)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([40, 460])
 .domain([0, 100]);
 
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
 .tickFormat(function(d){ return d + "\u00B5mol/L"})
    .ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
 .call(axis);
```

```css
text { font-size: 14px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```